# find argument issues while on zsh

Tags: bash, oh-my-zsh

I have this strange issue executing the following command on zsh using powerlevel10k. Honestly I have no clue what could be causing it, however, I removed all oh-my-zsh plugins just to try without luck.

The issue is as simple as:

```
❯ find -name *.yaml
zsh: no matches found: *.yaml
```

If I go to bash and execute the same command it works as intended

```
❯ bash
xxxx@merlin:~$ find -name *.yaml
./go/src/github.com/ ... 
{regular result list}
```

Do you have any ideas ? thanks in advance

Comment: [This issue](https://superuser.com/a/1217774/432690). The behavior of Zsh vs Bash explained at the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1607656/432690).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell is likely to be expanding `*.yaml` in the current directory (not found), so you need to escape it to make it work in find:

```
 find -name \*.yaml
```

If there was a file say suffix `xyz.yaml` in the current directory, your find command may adjust to explicit match on filename `xyz.yaml`, and not any ending `.yaml`:

```
 find -name xyz.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prevent shell expansion is to use single quotes around the wildcard character.

find -name '*.yaml'